# jQuery appendTo does not work under $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-post

```
// plays a card into table.
// this code works. rendered card is appending into the table.
    var playCard = function(card){
        var renderedCard = renderCard(card);
        $('#'+renderedCard.id).appendTo('#flop');

// but this one does not work.
var playCom = function(){
        $.post('/api/comPlay', function(data){
            var renderedCard = renderCard(data.card);
            $('#'+renderedCard.id).appendTo('#flop');
        });
    };
```

I check the returned value from `$.post`. `data.card` gives the correct value. I create a div html with my `renderCard` function. That function works correctly as you see. But under `$.post` not.

I am stuck. Is there something special that i must know about `$.post`?

Thank you.

**update** :

```
var renderCard = function(card){
        var create = document.createElement('div');
        create.className = 'cardBig';
        create.id = card;
        return create;
    };
```

Comment: If you do console.log(data), in the $.post function, what does the console say?

Comment: It's asynchronous? If `card` (above) === `data.card` (below), then there should be nothing different. What exactly does "not work correctly"?

Comment: @jqueryrocks it says `Object {card: "H4"}` which is what i want exactly..

Comment: what is `renderedCard.id` is the element exists

Comment: What exactly does the "renderCard" function do?  What does it return?

Comment: @ArunPJohny i updated the question. Added renderCard function.It creates a div element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to "find" your newly-created DOM element.

```
$(renderedCard).appendTo('#flop');
```

should do it.

Also, since you're using jQuery anyway:

```
$('#flop').append($('<div/>', {
  className: 'cardBig',
  id: data.card
}));
```

will save you the extra function.

Answer (score 1):

In `renderCard()` method you are just creating a new html element but it is not rendered to the dom.

So your element lookup `$('#'+renderedCard.id)` will not work

```
$(renderedCard).appendTo('#flop');
```

Comment: @ali by the time `playCard` is called the element with id `renderedCard.id` is already added to the dom, that is why it is working

Comment: @ali You can shorten `playCard` to `var playCard = function(card){
    $('#' + card).appendTo('#flop');
}`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried selecting the id element first, like so:

```
 $(renderedCard).appendTo( $('#flop')[0] )
```